# bash command arguments

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, arguments

I have a bash script that, for reasons I won't discuss, cannot be made executable. However, I need to pass arguments to that script.

I have tried this:

```
bash MyBashScript.sh MyArgumentOne
```

But the argument `MyArgumentOne` isn't passed to the script. I know there must be a way to do this, can anyone help?

Comment: Works fine for me. How are you trying to access the arguments in the script?

Comment: *bash* uses `$1` (etc.), not `%1`…

Comment: In Bash (and other Unix/Linux shells) it's `$1`, `$2`, etc. Percent signs are for Windows CMD.

Comment: Oops, noob mistake, I had not done many bash scripts before, thanx... If one of you would add an answer, I would happily up vote and accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your given command should work. Try to debug with calling trough

```
strace -o all_system_calls.txt -f -ff bash MyBashScript.sh MyArgumentOne
```

one of the `all_system_calls.txt.<pid>` files created should contain something like

```
execve("/bin/bash", ["bash", "MyBashScript.sh", "MyArgumentOne"], [/* 71 vars */]) = 0
```

If so you know for sure that the argument is passed into your script.

Comment: I don't think strace exists on iOS :)